# Elastic Beanstalk instance not responding with https

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, ssl, amazon-ec2, https

I'm trying to setup https on my EB instance, which is runnning a django app, it currently works with http, but with https it times out. I've been through every step I thought I needed to:

1. Created self signed certificate with name being the domain (myapp123.vdfb.eu-central-1.elasticbeanstalk.com) and uploaded it to the Certificate Manager
2. Setup port 443 on the Load Balancer:
   [image]
3. Add rule on the security group attatched to the ec2 instance:
   [image]
4. Also add rule on the security group attatched to the Load Balancer:
   [image]
5. Also added these lines in my settings file in the django app:

   ```
   SECURE_PROXY_SSL_HEADER = ('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO', 'https')
   SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE = True
   CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE = True
   ```

After all of this, it still keeps not resolving when I try to access it with `https://...`.
What am I missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Depending on the EB stack, activating TLS does not automatically mean that it is being activated on the backend as well. You have two options:

## Terminate at the load balancer

`User Agent <-- HTTPS --> Elastic Load Balancer <-- Plain HTTP --> Backend`

Just change the "instance protocol" setting from HTTPS to HTTP. This terminates the TLS connection on the load balancer and talks unencrypted HTTP with the backend instance. If that fits your security demands, that would be the easiest and quickest solution, because you don't need to adjust your application.

## Terminate at the backend instance

`User Agent <-- HTTPS --> Elastic Load Balancer <-- HTTPS --> Backend`

In this case, you have to provide an HTTPS listener within your application stack. The stack is partially provided by AWS and depends on your deployment platform, so I would like to forward you to the official docs as they contain the best practices: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/https-singleinstance-python.html

Comment: Changing from HTTPS to HTTP on the Load Balancer <> Backend is a good solution, for me, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This process would be much easier if you had your own domain to assign HTTPS to, instructions at https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/configuring-https.html

However, continuing on myapp123.vdfb.eu-central-1.elasticbeanstalk.com, there are the following steps, though I do not know if they are available in the AWS region that you are using.

[elasticbeanstalk ssl without custom domain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18283507/elasticbeanstalk-ssl-without-custom-domain)
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/configuring-https-ssl.html
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/configuring-https-ssl-upload.html
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/configuring-https-elb.html

Answer (score 0):

You might need to update ARN of AWS Certificate manager in Load Balancer dashboard. From the first diagram, I see there is EB URL instead of certificate.

Following link might help you

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/classic/elb-update-ssl-cert.html

Comment: I created the certificate last week, are you suggesting I replace it? The link mentions I should replace it if the validation period ended, but it's not the case!